# Google Apps Script - add value to textbox in UiForm

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a password generator button in my Ui form. I want to have the generated value added to the textBox. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Code:**

```
function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication()
.setTitle('Password Generator')
.setHeight(200)
.setWidth(300);

var panel = app.createFormPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(4, 3)
.setId('formGrid');

//Password Label and Textbox
var passLabel = app.createLabel('Password'); // Label Password
passLabel.setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Arial", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#0040FF"});

var passTextbox = app.createTextBox() // Text Box Password
.setId('Password')
.setWidth('150px')
.setName('password');
```

Generate Password Button

```
var passwordGen = app.createButton("Generate Password")
.setId("passwordGen");
passwordGen.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("passGenFunction"));
app.add(passwordGen);

grid.setWidget(0, 1, passLabel)
.setWidget(1, 1, passTextbox)
.setWidget(1, 2, passwordGen)

panel.add(grid)
app.add(panel);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
}
```

Password Generator function Section

```
function password_generator() {
var confirm;
var length = 16;
var pass = "";
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%&?";

for( var i=0; i < length; i++)
pass += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
//Missing code: generator button clicked. Results placed into passTextbox//
return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was more simple : in the password_generator function, one single line :

`return UiApp.getActiveApplication().getElementById('Password').setText(pass);`

Comment: Hi Serge, Thank you for the one line code, but when I put the line in after `$ pass += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));` and remove `var app = UiApp.createApplication();` it generator does not work.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ag8NytPhOo00dEFjT0JIMDZsTmxlN1JLSFJ0TnJLNUE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer.

I needed to define `$var app = UiApp.createApplication();` under `$function passGenFunction()`. Then add `$textBoxId` and `$pass`in `$app.getElementById("Password").setText(pass);`